# XOR: are these two equivalent?

Tags: javascript

I saw this piece of code in the underscore.js source:

```
if ((!a && b) || (a && !b)) return false;
```

Is that equivalent to the following?

```
if (a ^ b) return false;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no. `&&` and `||` are logical operators, whereas `^` is a bit-wise operator.

But if your inputs are booleans (or integers from the set {0, 1}), then the semantics will be basically the same. If you can't guarantee these inputs, you can still ensure identical semantics thus:

```
if (!a ^ !b) return false;
```

(Assuming, of course, that `a` and `b` are plain variables, not complex expressions with side-effects.)

Comment: What do you mean by "plain variables, not complex expressions with side-effects"?

Comment: @Randomblue: Logical operators short-circuit. If the first argument to `&&` converts to false, the entire expression will be false, and the second argument isn't evaluated at all — likewise if the first argument to `||` is true. The `^` operator always evaluates both sides. In your first expression, if `!a` is false, `b` is skipped, `a` is true, and `!b` is evaluated. In the process, you evaluated `a` twice. If you replace `a` with `do_something()`, then `do_something` will be called twice, which might then execute a side-effect twice. `!a ^ !b` always evaluates each argument exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Those two are not the same because `a ^ b` is a bitwise xor function instead of a logical xor function. So, if `a = 1` and `b = 2`, then `a ^ b=3` but you would want a falsy value because both `a` and `b` are truthy.